# Find the latest build file in directory

Tags: bash, find

I need to get the latest build file in current directory . The logic is sth like this:

1. Search for pattern in given build directory
2. find the latest one among matched
3. return basename for latest file name

I got  this one so far but its not complete

```
   find  ./build  -iregex '.*/build_.*\.tar\.gz' -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

I am puzzled around sorting it to get latest one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having GNU `find`, you can use the following command:

```
find ./build  -iregex '.*/build_.*\.tar\.gz' -printf '%T@ %f\n' | sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

It uses `find`'s printf action to print the timestamps of the latest modification along with the filename (basename). Then it pipes it to `sort`, extracts the last line using `tail` and finally separates the name from the timestamp using `cut`.

Comment: I believe this is some gnu `find` as my `find` command on OSX doesn't support `-printf`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it was tested with GNU find. Didn't know that `-printf` isn't supported in the non GNU version of `find`

Comment: unfortunately I am using Mac machine

Comment: since build files names are format as build_%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.tar.gz. This seems to be working : `find ./build  -iregex '.*/build_.*\.tar\.gz' -type f |sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -d'_' -f4 |cut -d'.' -f1` . Thanks that is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

This `find` should work using `stat` and `sort`:

```
find ./build  -iregex '.*/build_.*\.tar\.gz' -type f -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} + |
    sort -rn -k1,1 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f2-
```

---

On OSX try this `sed`:

```
find ./build  -iregex '.*/build_.*\.tar\.gz' -type f -exec stat -f '%m %N' {} + |
    sort -rn -k1,1 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f2-
```

Comment: on Mac Osx I get `stat: illegal option -- c`. Probably that is for gnu find ?

Comment: Seems like I was using gnu-stat on my OSX (via home brew) I updated answer to use OSX `stat` now.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure Bash possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob nocaseglob

latest=
for file in ./build/**/build_*.tar.gz; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    [[ $latest ]] || latest=$file
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
done

if [[ $latest ]]; then
    echo "Latest build: ${latest##*/}"
else
    echo "No builds found"
fi
```